# use HootSuite Engagement-API to preview social-network messages in corporate website

Tags: facebook, oauth, social-networking

we need a way to provide our clients corporate-website with a list of their social-network activity.

That means that the website should show a list to preview/links to some of the latest posts/messages in our clients facebook-fanpage or twitter tweets whatever.

so i think it is an opportunity to create an HootSuite-Account http://hootsuite.com/, do all relevant posts, centralized by their interface, and then use their Engagement-Api to request the HootSuite-Backend by the Corporate-Website.

i am not sure if we can do that with the EngagementAPI, because of Authentification. 
Every visitor of the website should be able to see all the posts/messages without have to connect or authenticate by login.

Is this possible without any token or is there something like an application-token the website can use.

Any experience with that topic are welcome?